# vs code - php intellisense inside of quotes

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

I want to ask if someone knows about way how to enable autocomplete (intellisense) for variable names inside of quotes in visual studio code.

For example, php function [compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) takes literally name of variable as argument, so we have to place it to the function inside of quotes, just like this: `compact('posts')` and not `compact($posts)` . The problem here is that as long as its not stated with $, intellisense will not trigger any suggestions for available variables.

Currently Im using [php intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) as php intellisense extension for vs code. Is it matter of right extension or some setting of particular extension or am I trying to achieve something that is not currently available? (I would like to also achieve suggesting of paths with '.' notation inside of quotes that is typical for example for laravel where `view('posts.show')` = `view('posts/show')`)

Thanks

Comment: It would be rather impressive if any IDE or plug-in could do this reliably. The biggest issue is how would intellisense detect that your code is going to use the incoming string parameter as a variable name; it would have to be some mythical oracle or something.

Comment: PHPStorm does this with the Laravel plugin.  I'm not sure if there is something that complete for VS Code yet.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I have seen it working in sublime text and also in PHPStorm as well so it is possible. I also understand that this is not trivial problem to solve but it is definitely possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to partly solve this problem by changing of `editor.quickSuggestions` setting, just like this:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "strings": true
}
```

This will enable suggestions for strings as well, however suggestions for variable names in `compact()` function will still not work, looks like its more specific issue of php language server implementation in vs code.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings 
Go to Word Seperators

Remove " from the string that defines word separators